# Can you format 24-hour time string into 12-hour time string with AM/PM?

Tags: sqlite

I store some time values in sqlite in %H:%M string format (for example "15:43"), but I would like to get them out formatted in 12 hour format with AM/PM indicators (for example "3:43 PM"). Is this possible with sqlite (and if so, how), or do I need to do this in my application code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you extend sqlite with your own [custom function](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/create_function.html), you'll have to do this is code.

sqlite's [strftime](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) date formatting function only supports a small subset of its C counterpart, insufficient for your problem. [sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/lang.html) also lacks a selection construct like IF or CASE, making simple if/else impossible.

Answer (score 4):

Some pseudo code to help you on the way:

```
if (hourpart of time >= 12)
    subtract 12 from hours
    append string " pm"
else // hourpart < 12
    append string " am"
end if
```

In SQL you can accomplish this using the [CASE](http://doc.ddart.net/mssql/sql70/ca-co.htm) syntax.

---

After taking a closer look at the problem:

```
SELECT (CASE HOUR(myTimeColumn) >= 12 WHEN 1 THEN
         ((HOUR(myTimeColumn) - 12) + '-' + MINUTE(myTimeColumn) + ' pm')
       ELSE
         (HOUR(myTimeColumn) + '-' + MINUTE(myTimeColumn) + ' am')
       AS AmPmTime,
       someOtherColumn
FROM myTable
```

I'm not entirely sure that all of that is valid SQLite syntax, but you should be able to correct the bugs.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few special situation that are covered here. I'm using 'now' as a source, but you can adjust it for your string:

```
select
  CASE 
  --For 00:05, for example.
  WHEN (strftime('%H', 'now', 'localtime') - 12) = -12
  THEN  '12:' || strftime('%M', 'now', 'localtime') ||' '|| 'AM'
  --For 12:05, for example.
  WHEN (strftime('%H', 'now', 'localtime') - 12) = 0
  THEN '12:' || strftime('%M', 'now', 'localtime') ||' '|| 'PM'
  --other am time
  WHEN (strftime('%H', 'now', 'localtime') - 12) < 0
  THEN  strftime('%H', 'now', 'localtime') ||':'||
    strftime('%M', 'now', 'localtime') ||' '|| 'AM'
  ELSE
  --other pm time
    (cast(strftime('%H', 'now', 'localtime') as integer) - 12) ||':'||
    strftime('%M', 'now', 'localtime') ||' '|| 'PM'
  END here_you_go_usa;
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it in your application. Store it in normal 24h format in the database. In the database it can be stored as a Date entry instead of a string (correct me if im wrong)

Answer (score 0):

As PoweRoy recomended, this belongs in the application.

It is recommended that any kind of data stored of used in communication uses a standard, locale-insensitive format: http://www.mihai-nita.net/article.php?artID=20051025a

Answer (score 0):

Here's a **working one..** Thanks to Tomas

```
SELECT 
    PatientName, 
    CASE WHEN 
        StrFTime('%H', AppointmentTime) % 12 = 0 THEN 12
        ELSE StrFTime('%H', AppointmentTime) % 12 END 
    || ':' ||
        StrFTime('%M', AppointmentTime)
    || ' ' ||
    CASE WHEN
        StrFTime('%H', AppointmentTime) > 12 THEN 'PM'
        ELSE 'AM' END   
    `APP_TIME`
From Patients;
```

**OUTPUT**
Abdul Salim, 12:05 PM

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Abdul Salim only returns PM whichever value is found because of a tiny mistake at the end of the last CASE WHEN

```
 SELECT
    username, 
    sqlaction,
    change_date, 
    CASE WHEN 
        StrFTime('%H', change_date) % 12 = 0 THEN 12
        ELSE StrFTime('%H', change_date) % 12 END 
    || ':' ||
        StrFTime('%M', change_date)
    || ' ' ||
    CASE WHEN
        StrFTime('%H', change_date)-0 >= 12 THEN 'PM'
        ELSE 'AM' END   
    as Time
From logs;
```

OUTPUT:

| username | sqlaction | change_date | Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| tcoto | UPDATE | 2023-09-15 11:37:21 | 11:37 AM |
| trot | UPDATE | 2023-09-15 11:57:57 | 11:57 AM |
| tcoto | INSERT | 2023-09-18 11:24:59 | 11:24 AM |
| tcoto | INSERT | 2023-09-18 11:25:05 | 11:25 AM |
| tcoto | UPDATE | 2023-09-18 16:34:51 | 4:34 PM |
| Toto | UPDATE | 2023-09-18 16:43:56 | 4:43 PM |
| tcoto | UPDATE | 2023-09-18 16:45:50 | 4:45 PM |
| tcoto | UPDATE | 2023-09-18 17:17:22 | 5:17 PM |