# How to search a column in an SQLite database for specific text?

Tags: android, sqlite, search, text

More specifically, the first two columns of my read-only database are the row number (the _id integer primary key), and a date and time in the text format 7/21/2011  HH:MM:SS PM. In my Android app, the user selects a start and end time (HH:MM), and then data about that time interval is displayed graphically. How do I search this second row of my database for the inputted times?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So if your Date Column contains TEXT(since there is no DATE in SQLite), you should use the SQLite function

```
    strftime(format, timestring, modifier, modifier, ...)
```

See docs [SQLite Date functions](http://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

So you SQL query may look something like this:

```
    SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE strftime('MM-DD-YYYY HH:MM:SS', date_column) < strftime('MM-DD-YYYY HH:MM:SS', '7/21/2010 22:00:00')
```

where the last date parameter will be the inputted date.

Comment: I am using a 12 hour clock. Is there any way to add AM/PM to the query?

Comment: I am afraid that you will have to do this in code. Here is a link that can help you solve you problem [SQLite AM/PM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/535855/can-you-format-24-hour-time-string-into-12-hour-time-string-with-am-pm). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with SQL time commands. If you select all rows and then process them in the java code using Date objects and their .compareTo() methods you can only display rows of interest to your user.